# Disabled buttons on dark background are not shown properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some buttons on Panel with dark background. Normally, when the panel is disabled, text on Label is grayed out, as well as text on the Button, so the user can see they are disabled. But when Panel has dark background set, the gray-out color is different and disabled button looks too similar to enabled button. This happens only when Button has UseVisualStyleBackColor set to true.

What can I do to make it visible for user that the button is disabled? (assuming I want to have dark background and UseVisualStyleBackColor)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

In your form *load* event set

```
SomeButton.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
SomeButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

or set the above properties to the *button* manually in designer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! But it needs to be done in that order, because setting BackColor sets UseVisualStyleBackColor to false automatically. Also I noticed that by default, when button is added to Panel, its BackColor is set to the same value as of Panel, that's why it was shown differently.